# how to get the readonly field value using selenium

Tags: selenium

I have read only field on Webpage as

```
<div id="dspIdDescriptionDet-inputEl" class="x-form-display-field" role="input" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="width: 100%;">2010-RR3 XIIIA9 20360726 FLT</div>
```

When I'm trying to get the display value (`"2010-RR3 XIIIA9 20360726 FLT"`) using `getText()` or `getAttribute("Value")` using Webdriver, its fetching nothing.

error on eclipse:

```
expected:<2010-RR3 XIIIA9 20360726 FLT> but was:<null>
```

code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dspIdDescriptionDet-i‌​nputEl']")).getAttri‌​bute("value"))
```

Comment: Please provide your locator code. By which means do you try to reach the element?

Comment: the code is `driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='dspIdDescriptionDet-inputEl']")).getAttribute("value"))`.

Comment: Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dspIdDescriptionDet-i‌​nputEl']")).getText());`

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait? It may be that the element is present but takes a bit for the data to populate into the field.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Issue resolved after adding wait.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer. If you would, accept it so the question gets marked as answered. Also, you should upvote any/all answers that you found useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer since it turned out to be the issue...

I would try adding a wait. It may be that the element is present but it takes a bit for the data to populate into the field.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the text of an element which has a unique id try using:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dspIdDescriptionDet-inputEl")).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have use below code for my usecase :**

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '**my xpath**')
aria_readonly_value = element.get_attribute("aria-readonly")
logging.info(aria_readonly_value)
assert aria_readonly_value == "true"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).